# Error al ejecutar el comando ng generate component

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, angular5

Actualicé mi proyecto angular 4 hacia la 5 y todo funciona bien. Pero cuando ejecuto el comando `ng generate component nameComponent` me lanza este error

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"path":"/src/app/...","prefix":"app","styleext":["css","scss"],"inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"
Default","spec":true,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"export":false,"entryComponent":false}
Errors:

  Data path ".styleext" should be string.
```

Sin embargo los demás comandos por ejemplo para generar class, servicios, etc. me funcionan bien.¿Por qué me pasa esto?

Answer (score 0):

La causa del error es porque mi fichero `angular.json` especificaba lo siguiente:

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext":["css",
       "scss"
       ]
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
```

al cambiarlo por este

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext":"css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
```

ya todo funciona bien. También funciona si no le especifico el `schematics` al proyecto:

```
"schematics": {}
```